# LocalDataSourceJobStore spring managed transaction configuration

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler, transactional

I'm facing issues in getting the configuration of spring 4.x and quartz 2.2.1 to work for having transactional operations.

The configuration that i am using can be found below :

```
<bean id="quartzScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
      p:jobFactory-ref="acquistionServiceJobFactory" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
      p:transactionManager-ref="transactionManager">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="xxxJob"/>
            <ref bean="yyyJob"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">${org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">${org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck">true</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export">${org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.objectName">${org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.objectName}</prop>

            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.class">${org.quartz.threadPool.class}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">${org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">${org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread">
                ${org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread}
            </prop>

            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix">${org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">${org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass}</prop>
            <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">${org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<!--  Quartz Scheduler Transaction Propagation -->
<tx:advice id="quartzSchedulerAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" propagation="SUPPORTS" />
        <tx:method name="set*" read-only="true" propagation="SUPPORTS" />
        <tx:method name="is*" read-only="true" propagation="SUPPORTS" />
        <tx:method name="insert*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="update*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="delete*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="schedule*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="org.quartz.SchedulerException"/>
        <tx:method name="pause*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="resume*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="run*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="update*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="delete*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="toggle*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
        <tx:method name="clone*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<tx:advice id="localDataSourceJobStoreAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" read-only="false" propagation="REQUIRED" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="quartzSchedulerPointcut"
                  expression="execution(* org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler.*(..))" />
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="quartzSchedulerAdvice" pointcut-ref="quartzSchedulerPointcut" />
</aop:config>
```

quartz.properties content :

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=Quartz2Scheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true
org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.objectName=Jobscheduelr:group=quartz,name=QuartzScheduler

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=20
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true

org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true

org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ2_
```

Since quartz runs in a clustered environment, the log contains often the following log statements :

```
 No record found for selection of Trigger with key : ...
```

which is actually linked to a quartz bugfix : https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-386

In the situation what I'm facing however, this problem appears due to the fact that the operations on the LocalDataSourceJobStore are not transactional.
I've searched extensively for an example project showing how to cover the transactional aspect between spring & quartz operations, but haven't found yet a sample which covers it.

I'm expecting that while I am on the execute(JobExecutionContext) method of the quartz job to be within an active transaction.

```
org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()
```

Snippet taken out from the javadoc of the class org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean :

```
 * The preferred way to achieve transactional execution is to demarcate
 * declarative transactions at the business facade level, which will
 * automatically apply to Scheduler operations performed within those scopes.
 * Alternatively, you may add transactional advice for the Scheduler itself.
```

On the other hand for cron & simple jobs, most of the operations are performed directly with the localDataSourceJobStore which is not part of the Spring container and is not taken into account by the transactional AOP advices.

Snippet taken out from the javadoc of the class org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore

```
* Operations performed by this JobStore will properly participate in any
* kind of Spring-managed transaction, as it uses Spring's DataSourceUtils
* connection handling methods that are aware of a current transaction.
```

Obviously it seems that there must be a way to include LocalDataSourceJobStore in Spring transactions, but i don't seem to find it for the calls that originate from the method org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread#run() 
Can anybody give me a hint in this regard?

Comment: Hi @skaffman, / marius_neo did you find any solution for this issue?